# How to reset a page, and how to score a win in hangman

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have my hangman page essentially working, but Im looking to tweak it.

Firstly, my failed guesses are adding up correctly, and the alert pops up when you reach 6 failed try's. The problem im having at the moment is I cant figure out how to reset the page. I've tried some renditions of "$(':reset');" but none have worked for me so far. Currently after the alert pops up you click ok, and then can continue guessing, which is obviously not working as intended.

Secondly, I don't know how to recognize a win in code form. When you play the game, you can guess all the correct letters, but upon guessing the final letter, nothing actually happens. I need to find a way for it to recognize that all letters have been identified.

Thank you ahead of time!

JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9mxxwu0o/

Html -

```
<body>


<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">
<input type="button" id="but" value="Start"/>
<div id="hangman-jquery">
    <div id="word"></div>
    <div id="alpha"></div>
</div>
</form>

<div id="win">
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="hangman.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS -

```
function hangman(word) {
    var trys = 0;
    var guess = 0;
    var alpha = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $.each(alpha.split(''), function(i, val) {
        $('#alpha').append($('<span class="guess">' + val + '</span>'));
    });
    $.each(word.split(''), function(i, val) {
        $('#word').append($('<span class="letter" letter="' + val + '">-</span>'));
    });
    $('.guess').click(function() {
        var count = $('#word [letter=' + $(this).text() + ']').each(function() {
            $(this).text($(this).attr('letter'));
        }).length;
        $(this).removeClass('guess').css('color', (count > 0 ? 'green' : 'red')).unbind('click');

        if (count > 0) {
        $('#win').text("Correct Guess");
        } else if (count <= 0) {
        trys++;
        $('#win').text("You have tried to guess the word and failed " + trys + " times");
        }
        if (trys == 6) {
        alert("You have guessed six times, you lose");
        trys = 0;
        $("#win").text("");
        $(this).val('');

        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#but').click(function() {
        var options = new Array("DOG", "CAT", "BAT", "HORSE", "TIGER", "LION", "BEAR", "LIGER", "DOOM", "SPIDER", "TREES", "LAPTOP");
        var random = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
        hangman(options[random]);
    });
});
```

Comment: I posted a solution that detects win condition and resets game state. Win detection is easy in this case: just compare the `word` passed to the `hangman()` function with the `.text()` property of the element that contains the word (since correct word will not contain dashes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where functions come in handy: reusable blocks of code.

Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2azzvscs/

(Scroll down and "Run Snippet" to try it out right inside of stack overflow)

In this case you should move code for starting the game to a separate function (I called it `newGame()` in example below) that can be called when you need to start a new game after a win or loss.

Also made it detect win condition and ask user to play again.

I also recommend using `html()` instead of `append()`; I converted your code to use an array of strings that gets joined into a single DOM fragment that will replace the previous content. Usually, appending to DOM reflows the document, and so you want to do this as little as possible in a loop. (doing it this way also allows your game state to start over without reloading the page from server, which is totally unnecessary in this case).

```js
function hangman(word) {
    var trys = 0;
    var guess = 0;

    var alpha = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    var strBuilder = [];
    $.each(alpha.split(''), function (i, val) {
        strBuilder[strBuilder.length] = '<span class="guess">' + val + '</span>';
    });
    $('#alpha').html(strBuilder.join(''));
    strBuilder = [];
    $.each(word.split(''), function (i, val) {
        strBuilder[strBuilder.length] = '<span class="letter" letter="' + val + '">-</span>';
    });
    $('#word').html(strBuilder.join(''));

    $('.guess').click(function () {
        var count = $('#word [letter=' + $(this).text() + ']').each(function () {
            $(this).text($(this).attr('letter'));
        }).length;
        $(this).removeClass('guess').css('color', (count > 0 ? 'green' : 'red')).unbind('click');

        if (count > 0) {
            $('#win').text("Correct Guess");
        } else if (count <= 0) {
            trys++;
            $('#win').text("You have tried to guess the word and failed " + trys + " times");
        }
        if ($("#word").text() === word) {
            if (window.confirm("You win! Play again?")) {
                newGame();
                $("#win").text("");
            }
        }
        if (trys == 6) {
            alert("You have guessed six times, you lose");
            $("#win").text("");
            newGame(); // begin new game
        }
    });
}

function newGame() {
    $("#win").text("");
    var options = new Array("DOG", "CAT", "BAT", "HORSE", "TIGER", "LION", "BEAR", "LIGER", "DOOM", "SPIDER", "TREES", "LAPTOP");
    var random = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
    hangman(options[random]);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#but').click(newGame);
});
```

```css
.guess
{
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.guess:hover
{
    background-color: #eee;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">
        <input type="button" id="but" value="Start" />
        <div id="hangman-jquery">
            <div id="word"></div>
            <div id="alpha"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="win"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="hangman.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh man, you gave me the jackpot. Not only am I looking over your code and thinking about how much harder I can make things at time, but I'm super appreciative of how you break it down for me. The CSS was totally unnecessary but greatly appreciated. You really went above and beyond, thank you a ton!

Answer (score 2):

Just add this after your loose message:

```
$("#word, #alpha").html("");
```

Like this:

```
if (trys == 6) {
    alert("You have guessed six times, you lose");
    $("#word, #alpha").html(""); // This
    trys = 0;
    $("#win").text("");
    $(this).val('');
}
```

**Here is WORKING code:**

http://jsfiddle.net/9mxxwu0o/3/

I just added couple easy things to it, no tinkering or making it run bit faster, if you want that, then **nothingisnecessary** provided you an great answer.

Comment: Thank you for some clarification on the matter. I didn't think of using #word and #alpha like that. Simple yet I completely overlooked it. I very much appreciate the help Michael!

Comment: Im glad to help you. But stil, nothingnecessary gave you really great answer. Too bad I am working on one web right now, so I had no time to play with it. Anyway, enjoy and when youll have fully working page, send me the link. Ill gladly play couple games.

Comment: Lol, no it's cool. I didn't make a flashy game, it was merely to understand the code behind it. So what Nothingnecessary posted is essentially what I ended with. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could simply reload the page to reset the game?

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: True, that is an option. I was hoping to reset within the page if possible though.